# Multiple Thread Delphi Stop

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have a frame, inside it I have a thread, the creation of this front and at runtime, each click that give the button it creates a new frame and may have innumerable within the form. the problem is that ... I create the first, the thread starts normal when I create the second, the first thread to, and the second begins, if I click again, the first and second stand still and the third begins, if I close the third, the second back to work, because this happens?
thank you

```
constructor TMy_Thread.Create(fraConnect : TfraConnect);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  Priority        := tpTimeCritical;
  FreeOnTerminate := true;
  fraConnectT     := fraConnect;
end;

procedure TMy_Thread.Execute;
begin
  Synchronize(Teste);
end;

procedure TMy_Thread.TEste;
var
  iSize : Int64;
  iCnt  : Integer;
  Msg : TMsg ;
begin
  inherited;
  with fraConnectT do begin
    While not Terminated do begin
      Log(fraConnectT.Name,'');
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
  end;
end;


////////////////

procedure TfraConnect.Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Sc : TMy_Thread;
begin
  Sc                    := TMy_Thread.Create(Self);
  try
    iTela            := 0;
    Sc.Execute;
  finally
    Sc.Terminate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what problem you're describing, especially since we can't see any code. Can you provide a sample to demonstrate your issue? On the other hand, based on your explanation, it sounds like you need a thread pool, but can't be too sure without knowing the context.

Comment: Please read your own question and ask yourself if you explained your problem in a way that will allow people to answer.

Comment: Please show some actual code.  It sounds like your frame/thread is trying to access something that is being locked when creating a new frame/thread and unlocked when freed, thus blocking access to earlier frame/thread instances.  Hard to say for sure without seeing what you are really doing.

Comment: Many mistakes here. Leaking the thread. Calling Execute from the main thread. Synchronizing a non terminating function. You need to start again and make sure you have better understanding. I'm struggling to see why you need a thread. And until you have better understanding you need to avoid threads which are beyond your current expertise.

Comment: And how do I fix this? @RemyLebeau

Comment: It example of the correct way to do this. @DavidHeffernan

Comment: Seriously, tpTimeCritical priority? That means you don't have any idea about what you are doing. There is almost no excuse for this. You also can't call ProcessMessages in the thread procedure (although it is now executed in the main thread - it is not supposed to be there).

Answer (score 6):

You are not using `TThread` correctly. You are not starting the thread (so it does not free itself when terminated), you are calling `Execute()` directly, you are `Synchronize`ing the entire body of `Execute()`. So `Execute()` runs in the main thread, calling `ProcessMessages()` to allow a new button click, which calls `Execute()` blocking the previous `Execute()` until the new `Execute()` exits, and so on.  That is why you are experiencing the symptoms you are seeing.

To fix this, you need to do the following:

- In the thread constructor, call `inherited Create(False)` instead.  This allows the thread to start running automatically.  Otherwise, you have to call the thread's `Resume()` or `Start()` method after the constructor exits.
- remove `Execute()` from `Click()`. Let the running thread call `Execute()`.
- remove `ProcessMessages()` from `Teste()`. There is never a need to call `ProcessMessages()` in a thread (unless it is being called inside of `Synchronize`d or `Queue`d code running in the main thread, but even then it should be avoided when possible).
- only `Synchronize()` small code blocks that actually *need* to run in the main thread - code that does not work in a secondary thread, code that needs to access the UI, code that needs to access a resource shared by multiple threads, etc.  The bulk of your thread code should NOT be `Synchronize`d, that defeats the purpose of using a thread in the first place.

Try something more like this:

```
type
  fraConnect = class;
  TMy_Thread = class(TThread)
  private
    fraConnectT : TfraConnect;
    procedure DoLog;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(fraConnect : TfraConnect);
    property Terminated;
  end;

...

constructor TMy_Thread.Create(fraConnect : TfraConnect);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  Priority        := tpTimeCritical;
  FreeOnTerminate := true;
  fraConnectT     := fraConnect;
end;

procedure TMy_Thread.Execute;
begin
  with fraConnectT do begin
    While not Terminated do begin
      // assuming Log() is not thread-safe...
      Synchronize(DoLog);
      Sleep(100);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMy_Thread.DoLog;
begin
  Log(fraConnectT.Name,'');
end;
```

```
type
  TMy_Thread = class;
  TfraConnect = class(TFrame)
    Start: TButton;
    Stop: TButton;
    StartClick(Sender: TObject);
    StopClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Sc: TMy_Thread;
    procedure ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
  end;

...

procedure TfraConnect.StartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (not Assigned(Sc)) or Sc.Terminated then
  begin
    Sc := TMy_Thread.Create(Self);
    Sc.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
    Sc.Resume; // or Sc.Start;
  end;
end;

procedure TfraConnect.StopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(Sc) then
    Sc.Terminate;
end;

procedure TfraConnect.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sc = Sender then
    Sc := nil;
end;
```

Comment: Code that access a shared resource is usually best protected by a lock. So I'd go further in advising to limit the use of Synchronize. I'd only usee that for code that has an affinity to the UI thread.

Comment: `TThread.Resume` is deprecated. `TThread.Start` should be used to start newly created thread. [TThread.Resume](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Classes.TThread.Resume)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: true, but I did not want to presume, considering Kernel did not say which version of Delphi is being used. `Start()` is for D2010+.

Comment: I see your point, however I think that is something worth mentioning in answer.